# Can we add multiple files using a single ASP.NET FileUpload control?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, controls, upload

We need to upload multiple files using ASP.Net in one go. One option is to use the ASP.Net FileUpload control but it seems that it can't upload multiple files in one go. Any other option or ASP.Net FileUpload control can do multiple uploads in one go with some tuning?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick snippit. Hope this works for ya!

```
string SaveIt = "C:\\UploadsTesting\\";
        if (Merica.HasFiles)
        {
            foreach (HttpPostedFile hpf in Merica.PostedFiles)
            {
                string[] endnameparts = hpf.FileName.Split('\\');
                string endname = SaveIt + endnameparts[endnameparts.Length - 1];
                if (File.Exists(endname))
                {
                    endname = SaveIt + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "___" + endnameparts[endnameparts.Length - 1];
                }
                hpf.SaveAs(endname);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No. One HTML upload element can upload exacly one file.
To upload multiple files you can generate multiple upload controls on client side or use flash\silverlight.

Comment: Any exmpele or resource for flash\silver light?